# Accessing the URL from a GUID iOS App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xml, json

I am receiving an XML feed of data with the GUID attached to it for an iphone application. This GUID represents a URL. I now want to be able to access the URL from the given GUID. Is this possible?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier  ???

Comment: How are you converting URLs to GUIDs and GUIDs to URLs?

Comment: can you post some more data? URL and GUID? XML feed?

Comment: GUID is an acronym meaning Globally Unique IDentifier. It is not a term for a specific format or technogy. Nobody here will be able to help you unless you specify what technology or library you are using to generate your GUIDs.